# java.lang.LinkageError: Error reading class bytes: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.MenuImpl

Tags: java, eclipse, class, byte, linkage

I was working in Eclipse and my computer suddenly crashed. I rebooted my computer and tried to open Eclipse again but I get now the following error when I try to open Eclipse: "Unable to open Eclipse, see log file C:..."

The log file gives me this info:

```
    !SESSION 2017-03-11 09:45:11.196 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M20161124-1400
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=nl_BE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-11 09:45:35.562
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: Error reading class bytes: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.MenuImpl
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.MenuFactoryImpl.createMenu(MenuFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.MenuFactoryImpl.create(MenuFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHelperImpl.createObject(XMLHelperImpl.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4XMIResource$8.createObject(E4XMIResource.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObject(XMLHandler.java:2238)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectFromFeatureType(XMLHandler.java:2179)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObject(XMLHandler.java:2071)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.createObject(XMIHandler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.handleFeature(XMLHandler.java:1876)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.processElement(XMLHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.processElement(XMIHandler.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:1008)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.startElement(XMIHandler.java:190)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1518)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.read(ZipBundleEntry.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.StorageUtil.getBytes(StorageUtil.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.BundleEntry.getBytes(BundleEntry.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:566)
    ... 64 more
```

How can I solve this (if possible without removing and reinstalling Eclipse)?

Thanks in advance

Freyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like at least one of the Eclipse plugin jars has been damaged (`org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_1.2.0.v20160229-1459.jar` to be specific).

Since you don't know what else has been damaged reinstalling Eclipse is the safest option.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!